# Lazy-loading grid: scroll a large, empty div that is mostly hidden by overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am currently implementing a large, lazily rendered grid, with the goal of being able to display many more rows and columns than you could if you just rendered them directly. To do so, I've implemented a solution where:

1. The grid is a container div that holds a `scroller` and `content` div. The `scroller` div is empty, and the `content` div displays whatever is visible on the screen.
2. The user scrolls in the container by scrolling the `scroller`.
3. Based on where the `scroller` div is, the `content` div renders different data for the content.
4. The `content` div translates itself around so that it stays positioned correctly.

Functionally, this allows us to render *very few* divs, while from the users perspective, they can scroll through their data as normal. This is necessary, given the data sizes I'm working with.

However, I need to be able to scroll the grid to a specific location (e.g. the 100th row, 3rd column). To do so, I need to be able to move the `scroller` div. However, as most of scroller div is hidden (by the grid container), I cannot figure out how to use the `scroll` or `scrollBy` functions to accomplish this. As the `scroller` element is mostly hidden, the `scroll` function cannot move it, as `scroll` only works in relation to the visible aspect of the element (I think!).

I striped down the grid to the **minimal reproducible example in the codepen here**: https://codepen.io/naterush/pen/WNOZGze (it was too big to be reasonable to put in this question). This just has a single row of data, and you can scroll to the right inside of it to see more data.

The only code that needs to be finished is the `scrollTo20` function. Any thoughts or comments or directions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to scroll `to` a specific point or `by` some step? And replacing from `scroller` to `container` works (but goes until 10th element)

Comment: Omg, genius. Scroll scrolls within the element. Not the element within itself. You rock. That's hours of my life I'll never get back!

Comment: Glad to know! Those hours were worth at least for learning. I'll post my answer just to in case you want... to ... accept (afterall, I'm almost 1k) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`Element.scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) is attached to the wrong element. If you want to scroll the div, consider changing the function to scroll from the outer div, not on a div within a container.

```js
let currNumber = 0;

function onScroll(e) {
  let { scrollLeft, scrollTop } = e.target;
  // First, move the content div to the correct place
  let xOffset = scrollLeft % 200;  document.getElementById('content').style.transform = `translate(${scrollLeft - xOffset}px, 0px)`
  // Then, update the divs inside the content div to have the correct numbers
  let startingNumber = Math.floor(scrollLeft / 200);
  
  if (currNumber != startingNumber) {
    console.log("Changing to", startingNumber)
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      document.getElementById('' + i).innerHTML = startingNumber + i;
  }  
  }
  
  
  currNumber = startingNumber;
}

function scrollTo20() {
  console.log("This should scroll the #scroller so that the div then ends up being displayed starts at 20")
 
  document.getElementById('container').scroll(20 * 200, 0); // point to container instead of scroller
  
}

document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1000px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

#scroller {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.row {
  display: flex
}

.row > div {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='app'> <div id='container'> <div id='scroller'/> <div id='content'> <div class='row'> <div id='0'> 0 </div><div id='1'> 1 </div><div id='2'> 2 </div><div id='3'> 3 </div><div id='4'> 4 </div><div id='5'> 5 </div></div></div></div></div><button onclick='scrollTo20()'> Scroll to 20</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: @testing_22 figured out the solution. The `Element.scroll` function scrolls within a div, not on a div within a container. I just had to change what I was trying to scroll.